# Checked if "a" link was clicked without DOM object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, velo

Im embedding a event calendar on wix and a search a means on a customize javascript section able to check if my link on calandar was clicked without HTML DOM object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngLJB.jpg)

Because the problem is Wix dosen't want use DOM object:

https://www.wix.com/velo/forum/coding-with-velo/help-using-document-htmlcomponent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me7N7.jpg)

Im trying this :

```
import $ from "jquery";

$("#none2").click(function(){
   console.log("button was clicked");
});
```

or

```
if(none2.getElementById('a').clicked == true)
  {
     // check if the link is clicked
  }
```

... but a think is incorrect...

Thanks for ur support

Answer (score 0):

Did you also see the wix example of chart.js? https://www.wix.com/velo/example/create-a-custom-chart

Since you don't have access to the document you do have access to a $w which is kind of similar to the dom. This way you can bind methods to the element you are watching.

Probably it should be something like the following:

```
$w.onReady(() => {
    $w('#yourcalendarid').on('click', function () {
        // Do you what you want to do here
    });
});
```